# In a WordPress plugin admin ajax call, which is the way of using the site's locale?

Tags: ajax, wordpress, plugins, locale

After upgrading to WordPress 4.7, I changed the language field from my profile to english, while the site's language is set to greek.

I have written a plugin that displays a widget. This widget is refreshing its content via an ajax call. As it is mentioned [here](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2016/11/07/user-admin-languages-and-locale-switching-in-4-7/) (see *Note about admin-ajax.php*), strings are normally returned in my profile's language (english), but I would prefer to have them in the site's locale (greek).

After adding the statement `switch_to_locale( get_locale() )` at the first line of the ajax call action handler, expressions using the default text domain like `__( 'Sunday' )` are indeed translated to greek. However, expressions like `__( 'Sunday', 'my-plugin-textdomain' )` are never translated.

My question is **how can I display strings from the plugin text domain in my site's (and not my profile's) locale during an ajax call?**

Note that:

- Before switching my profile's locale to english, everything worked fine (that is, all strings were translated to greek).
- I am loading the plugin's textdomain in a function triggered by the action *plugins_loaded*.
- Searching the internet didn't lead to helpful results as the feature of setting the user's locale is released recently in the latest version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a late answer but I found out how to load the related text domain before the AJAX call works today, needed to share here:

Add a hidden input field to your form or append to your data this:

```
<input type='hidden' name='lang' value='<?php echo get_locale();?>'>
```

or

```
{
   lang: '<?php echo get_locale()?>',
}
```

Then, just before your `load_*_textdomain()` function call, write this:

```
if (isset($_GET["lang"])) {
    $locale = $_GET["lang"];
    add_filter('determine_locale', function()use($locale){ return $locale; });
}
```

It'll switch the locale to the desired locale. Note, the locales are like `en_US` or `el` relative to your `.mo` filenames.

Comment: Nice answer. My working solution: I check whether I am `DOING_AJAX` and the `$_REQUEST['action']` has the appropriate value. Then, I short-circuit the `determine_locale` functionality by `add_filter( 'pre_determine_locale', 'get_locale' );`.

Comment: Hi! I can't use "determine_locale" inside a function, itsn't work, this only works outside of a function. That's why your hack doesn't work. 

But outside the function I can't get the value of the input "lang" from your example

Comment: "determine_locale" is a filter, which needs to be added before the related `apply_filters` is executed. That might be the reason you couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's sum up all the above comments and write normally and understandably for everyone.

1)Add input with name "lang" in your form

```
<input type="hidden" name="lang" value="<?= get_locale(); ?>">
```

2)Then in the function.php file, we check if the request is AJAX, and if there is a input with "lang" name, then we override the locale

```
if( wp_doing_ajax() && $_REQUEST['lang'] ) {
  $locale = $_REQUEST['lang'];
  add_filter('determine_locale', function() use ($locale) { 
    return $locale;
  });
}
```