# WPML string translation on woocommerce gateway (ajax issue)

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, translation, wpml

In woocommerce payment gateways it seem that some strings are not translated after an ajax call.

The related  strings are translated in WPML and they are showing before ajax loading of payment gateways.

**During loading:**

[image: During loading]

**Once loadded:**

[image: after ajax loading]

I have tried [this answer thread](http://%20https://wpml.org/forums/topic/woocommerce-ajax-calls-and-process_payment/) from WPML Forums:

```
add_action("init", function() {
    if (is_ajax()) { // and something else ???
        global $sitepress;

        $lang = $sitepress->get_current_language();

        if (isset($_SESSION['wpml_globalcart_language']) && ($_SESSION['wpml_globalcart_language']) != $lang) {
            // sanitize "$_SESSION['wpml_globalcart_language']" ???
            $sitepress->switch_lang($_SESSION['wpml_globalcart_language']);
        }
    }
});
```

But it does not work in my case.

How to allow string translation from payment gateways related to Ajax?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should better open a ticket in their support as WPML is a premium plugin.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54925655/916000